# How to fix mutableMapOf setting all data the same

Tags: android, firebase

I have a firebase database and i am setting its value using mutableMaps

Everything is working fine except for items prices and quantities they are added as the same value.

```
MainActivity.selectedItemsList.forEach { item ->

                      Log.d("ac1234","${item.itemPriceTotal}")
                      orderSubNode["totalPrice"] = item.itemPriceTotal
                      orderSubNode["totalQuantity"] = item.itemQuantity
                      orderNode[item.itemName] = orderSubNode

                  }

                  node["order"] = orderNode
```

[image: Firebase Database]

As you can see fresh potato and pineapple are added as the same and same quantity

But my logcat is showing different price and different quantity.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you create new instance of orderSubNode object?

Comment: @ZhebzhikBabich I think not, i only have ```val orderSubNode = mutableMapOf<String, Any>() ```, sorry im new to maps and tables and kotlin in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try something like this.

```
                  MainActivity.selectedItemsList.forEach { item ->
                      val orderSubNode = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()//creating new instance
                      Log.d("ac1234","${item.itemPriceTotal}")
                      orderSubNode["totalPrice"] = item.itemPriceTotal
                      orderSubNode["totalQuantity"] = item.itemQuantity
                      orderNode[item.itemName] = orderSubNode

                  }

                  node["order"] = orderNode
```

You add the same object every time and in any loop step you just changing it's properties. But you must create new instance of the object in every loop step. May be this is error.

Comment: Yes its working, thank you. But is that performance efficient?

Comment: Yes. There is creating object and in next loop step it destroys the object.